# How do I get the number of different or common elements between two vectors of strings?

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, stdstring

Is there a function to compare two string vectors to return the number of different (or the same) elements? Do I have to iterate over both of them and test item by item?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
// C++20
std::ranges::sort(v1);
std::ranges::sort(v2);
std::vector<std::string> v3;
std::ranges::set_intersection(v1, v2, std::back_inserter(v3));

// any version
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
std::vector<string> v3;
std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
```

Or, if you don't want to sort:

```
std::set<std::string> s1(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::set<std::string> s2(v2.begin(), v2.end());
std::vector<std::string> v3;

// C++20
std::ranges::set_intersection(s1, s2, std::back_inserter(v3));
// any version
std::set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
```

You may want to use a multiset if there could be duplicates in a vector.

Comment: OK, just need to add #include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

Comment: For `std::sort` you need to be certain v1 & v2 are not `const` and have a `operator<` implemented, which cannot be guaranteed in all situations.

Comment: if instead of a string is a class/struct, what std::methd must be implemented in the class to make it working with set_intersection? is that std::less or something?

would it be possible to edit the answer adding  an example with a class/struct type instead of a string? thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of an existing function but writing one yourself shouldn't be too much trouble.

```
int compare(const vector<string>& left, const vector<string>& right) {
  auto leftIt = left.begin();
  auto rightIt = right.begin();
  auto diff = 0;
  while (leftIt != left.end() && rightIt != right.end()) {
    if (*leftIt != *rightIt) {
      diff++;
    }
    leftIt++;
    rightIt++;
  }

  // Account for different length vector instances
  if (0 == diff && (leftIt != left.end() || rightIt != right.end())) {
    diff = 1;
  }

  return diff;
}
```

Notes

- Omitted `std::` prefix for brevity
- This function needs to be updated if it should handle `vector<string>` instances of different lengths

Comment: Thanks, i thought  i need to implement one...btw about your code, is there any specific reason you use auto for your local variables ? :) never saw auto been used until now

Comment: @vBx, In C++0x `auto` is re purposed for type inference.  In the `auto` uses above the compiler can infer the type for me so I don't have to write out the full `vector<string>::const_iterator` for both iterators.  It's very similar to C#'s `var` keyword

Comment: We can do better with count_if() can we.

Comment: @Martin York, wouldn't `count_if` require the two `vector<string>` implementations be combined into 1?  I believe `count_if` can only operate on a single iterator range.  True the predicate could be a mutating lambda which advanced the second iterator but that feels wrong.

Comment: the entire body of this function could be replaced with "return left == right;"

Comment: @TomSirgedas Wouldn't that just return whether or not the vectors are equal?

Comment: Yeah, `return left == right` would only return 0 or 1, but the function can return larger values, so my comment is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [set_difference()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) and [set_intersection()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/). In both cases you need to have your containers sorted beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (vector1 == vector2)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

The content will be compared from both vectors as per the below link documentation:

> Compares the contents of two vectors.
>
> 1-2) Checks if the contents of lhs and rhs are equal, that is, they
> have the same number of elements and each element in lhs compares
> equal with the element in rhs at the same position.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: `vector` supports both `==` and `<` type comparisons

Comment: @Andrew, yes it supports both, list mentioned in above link