# How to compare two vectors for equality element by element?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Is there any way to compare two vectors?

```
if (vector1 == vector2)
    DoSomething();
```

**Note:** Currently, these vectors are not sorted and contain integer values.

Comment: You mean you want to compare *irrespective* of the order of the elements in the vector? Otherwise, the above code should work.

Comment: A simple way to compare if you have two unsorted arrays which you want to check contain exactly the same values, is to **sort them**, and then use any one of the standard library methods to do a comparison.

Comment: If only it were this simple. VS2013 uses `std::equals` to implement `==`, then asserts at runtime because the iterators don't come from the same container(!) You have to set `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=1` (or `=0`) on all the projects that use, or might use, `==`. Arg!!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operators `vector` supports both `==` and `<` type comparisons

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out the [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) method of C++.

Comparing vectors has been discussed on **DaniWeb forum** and also **answered**:

[C++: Comparing two vectors](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/168611)

Check out the below SO post. It will be helpful to you. They have achieved the same with two different methods.

[How do I get the number of different or common elements between two vectors of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225820/compare-two-vectors-c)

Comment: Does that require the range to be sorted?

Comment: `lexicographical_compare` works here too, and eliminates having to deal with which range is the longer range.

Comment: Please post the details of the link you ar reffering here, if that link goes down in future, the whole answer becomes useless.

Comment: Bad answer. You should provide code sample not just links - what if they get down?

Comment: Note that this has no effect on unordered vectors with arbitrary item order: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b66b432234265b7e https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66300e8d00a16abf

Answer (score 100):

Your code (`vector1 == vector2`) is correct C++ syntax. There is an `==` operator for vectors.

If you want to compare short vector with a portion of a longer vector, you can use the`equal()` operator for vectors. ([documentation here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/))

Here's an example:

```
using namespace std;

if( equal(vector1.begin(), vector1.end(), vector2.begin()) )
    DoSomething();
```

Comment: std::equal() is also valid for plain arrays, while equality operator is not, for example: int a[1000], b[1000]; if(std::equal(a, a+1000,b)) DoSomething();

Comment: Good answer, except that it encourages bad practice (`using namespace std`) instead of using the more clear `std::equal`.

Answer (score 8):

**C++11 standard on `==` for `std::vector`**

Others [have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648810/895245) that `operator==` does compare vector contents and works, but here is a quote from the [C++11 N3337 standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/raw/master/papers/n3337.pdf) which I believe implies that.

We first look at Chapter 23.2.1 "General container requirements", which documents things that must be valid for *all* containers, including therefore `std::vector`.

That section Table 96 "Container requirements" which contains an entry:

> ```
> Expression   Operational semantics
> ===========  ======================
> a == b       distance(a.begin(), a.end()) == distance(b.begin(), b.end()) &&
>              equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin())
> ```

The `distance` part of the semantics means that the size of both containers are the same, but stated in a generalized iterator friendly way for non random access addressable containers. `distance()` is defined at 24.4.4 "Iterator operations".

Then the key question is what does `equal()` mean. At the end of the table we see:

> Notes: the algorithm equal() is defined in Clause 25.

and in section 25.2.11 "Equal" we find its definition:

> ```
> template<class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2>
> bool equal(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
>            InputIterator2 first2);
>
> template<class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2,
> class BinaryPredicate>
> bool equal(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
>            InputIterator2 first2, BinaryPredicate pred);
> ```
>
> 1 Returns: true if for every iterator i in the range `[first1,last1)` the following corresponding conditions hold: `*i == *(first2 + (i - first1))`, `pred(*i, *(first2 + (i - first1))) != false`. Otherwise, returns false.

In our case, we care about the overloaded version without `BinaryPredicate` version, which corresponds to the first pseudo code definition `*i == *(first2 + (i - first1))`, which we see is just an iterator-friendly definition of "all iterated items are the same".

Similar questions for other containers:

- [how to compare two std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182958/how-to-compare-two-stdset)

Answer (score 5):

According to the discussion [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/129168/) you can directly compare two vectors using

> ==

```
if (vector1 == vector2){
   //true
}
else{
   //false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If they really absolutely have to remain unsorted (which they really don't.. and if you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of elements then I have to ask why you would be comparing vectors like this), you can hack together a compare method which works with unsorted arrays.

The only way I though of to do that was to create a temporary `vector3` and pretend to do a `set_intersection` by adding all elements of `vector1` to it, then doing a search for each individual element of `vector2` in `vector3` and removing it if found. I know that sounds terrible, but that's why I'm not writing any C++ standard libraries anytime soon.

Really, though, just sort them first.

Comment: or may be create two `set` objects and compare them? Wouldn't that be easier if it is really required not to touch the vectors.

Comment: Depends how quick N lookup-and-remove operations are on a vector (`N*O(N)`) versus 2 set constructors sorting N elements (cplusplus.com's reference says "For unsorted sequences, linearithmic (N*logN)..") + a sorted comparison (`O(N)`).