# C++ check if vector a includes elements of vector b

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Could anyone tell me the simplest way to check if a vector A, includes an element of vector B?

it would be sort of:

```
   for every element in A (
   if (none of the elements in B exist in A) do something and B changes
   else (do nothing) )
```

I guess it could be done by with some loops. But is there a function that would make it easier?

Comment: Are the elements in A and B sorted? If not, would sorting them be allowed?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394149/how-to-efficiently-compare-vectors-with-c/17394298#17394298

Comment: I don't fully understand the logic of the program: the loop `for every element in A` loops over the `size` of `A` rather than the elements, as you don't seem to use the current element in the loop body (`if none of the elements in B exist in A` is independent of a specific element in A). Can you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually I just found a completely different approach to my problem. So I might close this post. Sometimes just writing down my question, helps me think!

Comment: What if there are two equal elements in the same vector should they be treated as a single object?

Comment: @remi000: Don't hesitate to post your solution as answer as well as it may help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STL `includes` function is designed for exactly this.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/includes/

Comment: I just found a complete different approach. But this would probably be my solution if not! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You `std::sort` them, then use `std::set_intersection` (or similar algorithm) to have included elements.