# Comparing two faces in android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, face-detection, image-comparison

I was developing an app which compare the face which is stored in SD card and the image shown in camera preview with the help of Surface view. I wrote code to detect the face and created a bitmap which will contain the face only. I need to compare this bitmap and the image in SDcard. I have searched about for java library, and got some links like [opencv](http://opencv.org/),[Eigenface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface). Which will be the better library? 
Please give me some good tutorial samples, it would be better if it explains the process behind the image comparison.

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure, that you should be comparing absolute vectors when doing so. Otherwise, if you compare pixels you'll have a problem I think, because of the different resolutions of the images. This link can be of help: `http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html`. Also  about that last part, take a look at this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248044/c-comparing-two-vectors`.

Comment: Your right comparing pixel may have problems. But how can we represent an image as vector?

Comment: A vector shape in Android can be/is represented as drawable. Now that this is in place, I think it's just a matter of scaling the two objects (it's not hard when dealing with vectors) and compare different parts of it. Anyway, what kind of an algorithm did you design/use in order to compare faces?

Comment: Here's some info on how to do this in a way: A facial recognition device (application in your case) is one that views an image or video of a person and compares it to one that is in the database (the other image in your case). It does this by comparing structure, shape and proportions of the face; distance between the eyes, nose, mouth and jaw; upper outlines of the eye sockets; the sides of the mouth; location of the nose and eyes; and the area surrounding the check bones. This subject is pretty interesting and I'm just wondering the prefered algorithm by you. :-)

Comment: Yea really its interesting one, but there will be lot of limitations and need some good algorithms. If such a app is there it will be a great contribution for augment reality applications. Do you know whether there is auto tagging in facebook? If there is such a thing then we can also implement such a thing right? There will be some method for face comparison.

Comment: No, I believe that the auto tagging in Facebook is related to Face detection, not facial recognition, those are two different algorithms, the latter one being considerably more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6050-howto-compareimages.jsp

The tutorial is very easy and the example works very well.

Comment: Can you please update the link?